# Adding row to Google Sheet with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have the following sheet [image: Google Sheet sample]

I'm using this nodejs module [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet)
I can read, edit the cells. No problem. But when I try to add a row I'm getting this error.

```
sheet #1: Sheet22 1000x26
Error: HTTP error 400 (Bad Request) - Blank rows cannot be written; use delete instead.
```

I looked for answers, they are all about editing the headers? But I can't seem to understand what's missing here since headers are already there.

Thanks a lot!

This is my code

```
saveTransaction: function(transaction){
        var creds = require('./credentials.json');
        var doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('xxxxxxxx');
        doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds, function (err) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          doc.getInfo(function (err, info) {
            console.log('Loaded doc: ' + info.title + ' by ' + info.author.email);
            sheet = info.worksheets[21];
            console.log('sheet #1: ' + sheet.title + ' ' + sheet.rowCount + 'x' + sheet.colCount);

            var newrow = {
                title: 'banana',
                type: 'fruit',
                url: 'http://example.com'
            };
            doc.addRow(17, newrow, function( err, rows ){
                if (err) console.log(err);
                console.log(rows);

              });

          })
        })
    },
```

Comment: The code you show here doesn't try to add a blank row, it tries to add a row with values. Also note that your example sheet has a repeated column label, while the row content you're adding has a key--`type`--that your sheet does not have. Probably this is user error since your specified keys do not match the targeted sheet's headers.

Comment: You should review the code of the library you are using: https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet/blob/0e5f3f7ae179a3fa9a931971ce8a47d858279496/index.js#L319-L333 The actual, official [Sheets REST API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) supports inserting blank rows. (and has [node.js documentation](https://apis-nodejs.firebaseapp.com/sheets/index.html)

Comment: Your first argument `17` to `doc.addRow()` seems strange. AFAIK ids of sheets are strings in form of `oh6fgn3`. (You can get them inside `info.worksheets[]` array via `doc.getInfo()`  api call).   My bet is that error message is red-herring and you have invalid worksheet id.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few possible problems here.  One is that you are adding to the `doc` instead of the `sheet`.  That might work--I'm not familiar with this part--but in case it helps others, I've gotten it to work using

```
sheet.addRow(newrow, function( err, rows ){
```

instead.

Secondly, and more likely, I have gotten this exact error message when my columns weren't set up to match the keys I was trying to add.  When none of them matched, it gave this error about an empty row.

For example:

```
doc.addWorksheet({headers: ['A', 'B', 'C']}, function(addWorksheetErr, newSheet) {
  if (addWorksheetErr) console.error(addWorksheetErr);
  else {
    newSheet.addRow({ A: 1, B: 'two', C: 3 }, function(addRowErr, row) {
      // this works fine
    });
    newSheet.addRow({ X: 4, Y: 'five', Z: 6 }, function(addRowErr, row) {
      // This will get the "Blank rows cannot be written; use delete instead"
      // error, because there's no A, B, or C in the row data.
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

GoogleSpreadsheet.addRow(worksheet_id, new_row, callback)

check worksheet_id

[look this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet#googlespreadsheetaddrowworksheet_id-new_row-callback)